# FrameLayout and TabHost - wrapping/scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scroll, android-wrap-content

I have a problem with my layout. On large screens tab content is wrapped (between the end of the content and the buttons at the bottom you will see only the background).

On the other hand on small screens scrollbar is visible. Is there a way to do some fit-to-screen trick?

My layout looks like this:

```
TabHost (fill_parrent, fill_parrent)
    LinearLayout (fill_parrent, fill_parrent)
        LinearLayout (wrap_content, wrap_content)
        FrameLayout (fill_parrent, fill_parrent)
        TabWidget (fill_parrent, wrap_content)
```

Code for FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp" />
```